# Critical Vulnerability in Magestore Store Locator extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, security

Magento released an announcement about a [critical Vulnerability in Magestore Store Locator extension](https://magento.com/security/news/critical-vulnerability-magestore-store-locator-extension)

There's been no patch released by the actual vendor - Magestore

Does anyone know:

1. What the vulnerability is?
2. How to patch it?

I've created a [github repo](https://github.com/treestonemedia/magestore-storelocator) that holds the original code of this extension, so you can see what the code is and perhaps see what the vulnerability is and suggest a patch?

The scope of functionality and code **are** available on the public github repo.

**Update**

Magestore released  a patch, it can be found here https://blog.magestore.com/store-locator-extension-patch/

According to them

> Please note that customers using Magento 1 are not affected by this issue.

Comment: This is not off topic as Magento released an announcement about this also the code is available in the linked git-hub repo

Comment: I will just put this here but there is a patch from Magestore https://blog.magestore.com/store-locator-extension-patch/

Comment: Thanks. This patch is only for magento2. According to magestore this vulnerability does not affect M1

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough we've run the security scan on our Magento2 development site which doesn't have the module installed, yet it flags it up.  What is the security scan actually testing?

Comment: I recommend you report your issue to securityinfo@magento.com. In your report please specify the affected store URL.